# Enum reflection

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I tried making this line in reflection but failed to make the `EnumTitleAction.SUBTITLE`:

```
new ClassA(EnumB.SUBTITLE, "Test");
```

How to do this?

I tried already to do this:

```
Class.forName("net.something.ClassA").getConstructors()[1].newInstance(/*Stuck with EnumB*/, "Test");
```

But I cant find out how to represent the EnumB part with reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum values are objects - just use it like you did in the first snippet:

```
Class.forName("net.something.ClassA").getConstructors()[1].newInstance
    (EnumB.SUBTITLE, "Test");
```

**Edit:**
As per comment below, the problem is getting an enum constant by reflection. The way to go at it is to use [`Class.getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()). If you know `SUBTITLES`'s location in `EnumB` this is fairly straight forward:

```
Class.forName("net.something.ClassA").getConstructors()[1].newInstance
    (Class.forName("net.something.EnumB").getEnumConstants()[4], "Test");
```

But as you may suspect, this coding style is pretty fragile.
A better approach would be to find it according to its name:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("net.something.EnumB");
Method nameMethod = clazz.getMethod("name");
Object value = null;
Object[] enums = clazz.getEnumConstants();

for (Object o : enums) {
    if (nameMethod.invoke(o).equals("SUBTITLE")) {
        value = o;
        break;
    }
}
Class.forName("net.something.ClassA").getConstructors()[1].newInstance
    (value, "Test");
```

Comment: I dont want to use the "EnumB" import. (I have a reason for this that I can't explain very well)

Comment: OK, wasn't clear on that from the OP. Are you allowed to change the code of `ClassA`?

Comment: No. I cannot change the code of both ClassA and EnumB because it are both classes of a librarie I use.

Comment: @BammerbomTheKing OK, now I better understand the question. Please see edited answer.

Comment: Testing it now. I will aprove it as soon as it works.

Answer (score 0):

Aside to Mureinik's answer you can also use `Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` so your code can probably look like (you will just need to suppress some compiler warnings)

```
String enumName = "your.EnumName";
String valueName = "SUBTITLE";
Class<? extends Enum> enumType = (Class<? extends Enum>) Class.forName(enumName);

Enum<?> enumValue = Enum.valueOf(enumType, valueName);
```

Now you should be able to use this `enumValue` in your code

```
Class.forName("net.something.ClassA").getConstructors()[1]
             .newInstance(enumValue, "Test");
//                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Just make sure that you will pass correct name of your enum value, otherwise `valueOf` will throw `IllegalArgumentException`.